# Why do the gravatars get blocked?

Tags: support, gravatar

We are using a site blocker (Websense, I call it webnonsense) to block URLs that are potentially dangerous or that the business deems 'un-worthy'.

Stack Overflow's avatars are blocked by Websense.

Any ideas why it does that?

Comment: Stackoverflow has a user profile picture uploader?
That's news to me, I do know we use gravatar as the avatar manager.

Comment: @johnnyArt: yeah, the OP meant gravatar; perhaps he thought it had some association with SO.

Answer (score 7):

Gravatar permits X-rated photos as avatars (sites can exclude them, as well as R- and PG-13-rated ones, from display). As such, it's not particularly surprising that Websense blocks it - they're notoriously trigger-happy.

Comment: Why the downvote? Both statements are true - Gravatar permits X-rated photos (but allows sites to exclude them from display), and Websense is notoriously trigger-friendly.

Comment: We use Websense and and I can view Gravatar fine. The IT department here must know what's up.

Comment: @snicker To my knowledge, Websense lets you pick what categories to block. I'm guessing Gravatar isn't in one of the categories your folks target.

Answer (score 3):

I'm unclear -- are you referring to the gravatar image URLs or the http://gravatar.com site itself?

Can you see this image?

[image]

If you can see that, then the gravatar *images*, at least, are not blocked.

Comment: My work proxy filters gravatar images. And most OpenID logins ;-p Gotta login outside of the office. But my work has an unnaturally sensitive filter.