# Script to automatically imgurify images when editing

Tags: feature-request, support, images, imgur, userscript

Occasionally I come across old posts (from before [the current `stack.imgur` setup](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4376/please-allow-image-uploads-directly-onto-the-site)) that contain images on other image-hosting services.

In order to forestall link rot, these should be placed on the Stack Exchange Imgur service. But it's troublesome to manually copy each image URL, upload using the dialog, and edit the question to replace the image, for each image being uploaded. **Is there a user script or other tool that can automate this?**

(I'm aware that this might not always be permissible due to copyright. But probably most images on SE are not creative works, e.g. just a screenshot demonstrating the issue, and [is therefore not copyrightable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threshold_of_originality). Some others are *de minimis* uses or are used only to identify, and so qualify as fair use. Obviously you should only use the tool for such images. And there are some images that are supposed to be hosted elsewhere, such as [Why do the gravatars get blocked?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33774/why-do-the-gravatars-get-blocked/33776#33776).)